# How to add bookmarks to multiple PDF files programmatically

Tags: python, pandas, pdf

I have a collection of ~300 PDF files, each one representing an archived journal. The issues average around 60 pages each.

I have a spreadsheet which details the starting pages and titles for articles within each issue/PDF, which I would like to add as bookmarks to the individual PDF files. There are about 9000 lines in the spreadsheet. When processed, Each of the 300 issues(each a separate PDF file) should contain the appropriate bookmarks for their respective articles.

I already have some simple code, in Python, using PyPDF2 and Pandas, which will insert a list of bookmarks into an individual PDF.

I should be able to bring the spreadsheet data into my program using pandas, select the first article by the issue filename, add the associated bookmarks to the PDF file and iterate to the next file.

I can get pandas to stack the bookmarks by filename, but I can't seem to select the bookmark and page data, or iterate through the filenames.

Sample code to have pandas group by filename:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#load the pdf filename and bookmark list
dfPdfBmk = pd.read_csv('bookmarkstest.csv')

marksGroupedbyFile = dfPdfBmk.reset_index().groupby(['filename','Subject']).sum()
print (marksGroupedbyFile.head())
```

Where I'm struggling is figuring out how to select the filename, Bookmark entry and page data...